# How Can I Package a Unity3D 5 Windows Application into a single exe file?

Tags: windows, package, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity3d development. I have created two versions of a 3D puzzle app, one for Mac and the other for Windows. Mac applications are created with the package contents contained within it. The Windows application is created with the exe file and a separate data folder with the same name as the exe file + suffix _Data. I want to create a single exe file to distribute on Amazon and other downloadable platforms. The problem I'm having is finding something where the data folder and the exe file have to be located at the same level.

I'm used to Apple devices but recently purchased a Windows laptop for testing.

I could not find anything in the Unity3D documentation on how to do this. The documentation talks about how to distribute the application to the Windows Store, something I don't plan to do. The only thing I could find on their forum was [one question](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/building-unity-3d-game-in-windows-as-a-single-exe-file.72654/) that was asked in 2011.

One of the suggested solutions, Enigma Virtual Box, I could not get to work because Unity3D requires that the exe file and the data folder be at the same level. I have also tried the trial for [Smart Packer Pro](http://www.smartpacker.nl/smartpackerpro.html) but I need a dll file as a starting point which I could not find in my Unity3D project folder.

All of the information I'm finding related to Windows packaging into a single exe file are at least five years old. None of them relate to packaging Unity3D applications. I have also searched microsoft.com and windows.com but could not find anything there.

**UPDATE 5/12/2016 14:15**

I installed Inno Setup and attempted to create a script for my application. It copied the exe file but created an empty data folder instead of copying the data folder I need to run the exe file. I checked to make sure that the folder name was correct in the script.

```
; -- myapplication.iss --
; Demonstrates copying 3 files and creating an icon.

; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING .ISS SCRIPT FILES!

[Setup]
AppName=myapplication
AppVersion=1.0 
DefaultDirName={pf}\myapplication
DefaultGroupName=myapplication
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\myapplication.exe
Compression=lzma2
SolidCompression=yes 
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Files]
Source: "myapplication.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"    

[Dirs]
Name: "{app}\myapplication_Data";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packing a Unity3D application is not *not* possible without 3rd party software.

[a bit more recent url (2014)](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/626239/a-truly-stand-alone-exe.html) suggests using [smart packer](http://www.smartpacker.nl/smartpackerpro.html), this however is a tool I personally never used before.

I tend to use [inno setup](http://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) as it seems a bit more professional, it eases up moving files, creating links (short-cuts) and uninstalling quite a bit as well. Simply said, this allows you to extract the exe and _data folder to the same folder, and create a shortcut to the exe.

**Follow up on edit**

> I installed Inno Setup and attempted to create a script for my application. It copied the exe file but *created an empty data folder instead of copying the data folder I need to run the exe file*. I checked to make sure that the folder name was correct in the script.

After selecting the main exe file during the `application files` part of the setup wizard, you can add a folder. Here you can select `yourgame_data` folder to be included in the installer. This however does require an additional step. After adding the folder, you need to set the `destination subfolder` to `yourgame_data` for it to be able to properly create the subdirectories. You can refer to [this picture guide](http://martin-klappacher.com/tutorial-windows-installer-for-your-unity-game/) for more information. I included the relevant step(s) below.

[image]

Comment: I just tried a free trial Smart Packer but I need a DLL file as input. I updated my question with that info. I found another link that also suggested Inno Setup. I will take a look at it. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I installed Inno Setup and created an install file. I could not execute the exe file because the statement I coded created an empty data folder instead of copying the contents of the data folder I had. I updated my original question with the script and more details. The [Dirs} section was the only one I could guess to use for the data folder.

Comment: Thanks so much @mxd. I was successful in getting this setup file created and the game executes as expected. I guess now all I have to do is decide on where to distribute this setup file in addition to Amazon. If you put a combination of your comments into an answer I will check it.