# UNITY - how to build a game without data folder?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to create a single .exe file for a game, with no data folder in unity? or combine the data folder to be inside the .exe file?

I know, it seems unusual request, or unusual issue, but its a key feature for my game.

Comment: Packing a Unity3D application is not not possible without 3rd party software.

Comment: @MarkiianBenovskyi are there 3rd party software you aware of that can do that? it will really help I dont even know what to search for!

Comment: If you do a simple search in google, on Unity3D package data into exe, you can find this first link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37191456/4697963

Comment: thanks! ill try that